# MySQL UNION is changing data format

Tags: mysql, union

I'm a little bit confused by this one.  I have similar tables for a bunch of different companies, trying to UNION them to get combined data.  However, the UNION changes the format of the data for one of my columns, which breaks the PHP code that utilizes that column.

The column in each table is:

```
branch tinyint(2) unsigned zerofill
```

Here is what happens selecting from just the first company (this is just an example, the actual select I am doing is way more complex):

```
SELECT DISTINCT branch FROM company1
+--------+
| branch |
+--------+
|     01 |
|     02 |
|     03 |
|     04 |
|     40 |
|     90 |
+--------+
```

And the second company:

```
SELECT DISTINCT branch FROM company2
+--------+
| branch |
+--------+
|     01 |
|     02 |
|     03 |
|     04 |
|     05 |
|     40 |
|     90 |
+--------+
```

And finally the UNION:

```
SELECT DISTINCT branch FROM company1 UNION SELECT DISTINCT branch FROM company2 

+--------+
| branch |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |
|     40 |
|     90 |
|      5 |
+--------+
```

You can see that I lose the leading 0s on the UNION.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You could put them back with LPAD. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad; that would change the result type to string, but actual integers really don't have (a specific number of) leading 0's.  Wait....how does that break php code? Do they normally come back as strings anyway?

Comment: You could update your PHP code to include the pad too.

Comment: Maybe I simplified too much for my example, in the actual statement I am using * for the SELECT and there are like 50+ columns with new ones added all the time, so I don't really want to move away from the * for the SELECT if possible.  Likewise I don't really want to mess around with the PHP much as a lot of it isn't even my code.

Comment: Your first problem is having different tables for different companies.  Unless you have really, really good reasons, then you should have one table with a company id.

Comment: I'm sure they were really, really bad reasons, but it's not my database.  And believe me, I've told management SEVERAL times that we should go backwards and fix things before moving forwards but you know, every new thing is always so urgent.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html):

> The ZEROFILL attribute is ignored when a column is involved in expressions or UNION queries.

Use `LPAD` explicitly in your queries:

```
SELECT LPAD(branch, 2, '0') AS branch
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT branch FROM company1 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT branch FROM company2
) AS x
```

Comment: Maybe I simplified too much for my example, in the actual statement I am using * for the SELECT and there are like 50+ columns with new ones added to these tables all the time, so I don't really want to move away from the * for the SELECT if possible.

Comment: Then you're screwed, you have conflicting requirements.

Comment: @AndrewNee 99.9999999999999999999999% of the time, if you can `UNION` `SELECT *` queries on multiple(x) tables, you have more tables(x-1 more) than you need.

Comment: @AndrewNee And if you have 50+ columns, with new ones being added all the time, you also have a design problem.

Comment: @Barmar These are customer records and there are a ton of things we keep track of.  Most of it is 1:1 so... I guess we could break it up into a few 1:1 tables but what would be the real advantage of that?  Keep in mind also that I pretty much never get the ok to go back and fix old mistakes here so even if there were a clear advantage, I doubt I could talk management into it.

Comment: OK. Often when we see people describing tables with lots of columns, it's because they have multiple columns that should actually be rows in another table, such as a column for each month of the year.

Comment: You can use `SELECT *, LPAD(branch, 2, '0') AS branch_padded` in your query, so you don't have to list all columns explicitly -- just the ones you want to do something extra with.